# Hasse Diagram Correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I've had to make Hasse Diagrams before, but they've always been, for lack of a better word, pretty. The lines haven't had any complicated back and forth or the like.

The jump that 4 and 6 have to do to go above 24 is killing me, same thing for that crossing line from 24 to 72. Is that correct? Is there a better way to do it? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, it's using the divides relation.

[image]

Comment: It’s possible to make a bit prettier, but there’s no way to avoid having two lines cross somewhere.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. Would I be correct in saying the Least Upper Bound of {4,6} is 24? And the Greatest Lower Bound of {4,6} is 2?

Comment: @Bob, No, because $36$ is also an upper bound of $24$ and it is not true that $24$ is less than $36$ in this poset (nor is it the other way around).  However, the greatest lower bound of $\{4,6\}$ is $2$.

Comment: @Hayden, do you mean that $36$ is also an upper bound of $4$ and $6$? I must not be understanding least upper bound. Is it the case then that there isn't a lub for the subset {4,6}?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean to say that $36$ is also a upper bound of $\{4,6\}$.  And yes, it is the case that there is no least upper bound for the subset $\{4,6\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, just noticed that I had accidentally said that.  Sorry, it's kind of late, perhaps I should stop reading questions on math.se. XD

Comment: What happened to $12$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean? It wasn't included in the poset.

Comment: I know, Bob, but I don't know why it wasn't included. Seems like someone ought to have put it in there.

Comment: @Hayden, just want to be sure I got this right. If 36 weren't in the poset, then 24 would be the lub right? It's the fact that 24 doesn't divide 36 ? The lub has to divide all upper bounds of the subset {4,6}?

Comment: @Bob Yes, that is correct, on both accounts.  Alternatively, if $24$ wasn't in there, then $36$ would be the least upper bound.